# Difference between MvcHtmlString.Create() and Html.Raw()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating a MVC-Project. Using MVC 4 and Razor. After building some pages I was wondering: what is the difference between

```
MvcHtmlString.Create()
```

and

```
Html.Raw()
```

Would be nice if you could help me here to understand that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is an excellent opportunity to look at the source code that's available to us for ASP.NET (https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/).

Looking at HtmlHelper.cs, this is the code for `Html.Raw()`:

```
public IHtmlString Raw(string value)
{
    return new HtmlString(value);
}

public IHtmlString Raw(object value)
{
    return new HtmlString(value == null ? null : value.ToString());
}
```

And this is the code for the MvcHtmlString class:

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    public sealed class MvcHtmlString : HtmlString
    {
        [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Security", "CA2104:DoNotDeclareReadOnlyMutableReferenceTypes", Justification = "MvcHtmlString is immutable")]
        public static readonly MvcHtmlString Empty = Create(String.Empty);

        private readonly string _value;

        public MvcHtmlString(string value)
            : base(value ?? String.Empty)
        {
            _value = value ?? String.Empty;
        }

        public static MvcHtmlString Create(string value)
        {
            return new MvcHtmlString(value);
        }

        public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(MvcHtmlString value)
        {
            return (value == null || value._value.Length == 0);
        }
    }
}
```

The most significant difference is that `Html.Raw()` accepts any object, while `MvcHtmlString.Create()` only accepts strings.
Also, `Html.Raw()` returns an interface, while the Create method returns an MvcHtmlString object.
Lastly, the Create deals with null differently.

Comment: Thank you for that answer! But which of these should be preffered?

Comment: @Julian:That depends on where the code is and what you easily have access to. Ususally I use neither, I just use `new HtmlString()`.

Comment: @Julian Like Guffa said: It depends on where your code is. In a view I prefer Html.Raw, but mainly because that is esthetically pleasing when reading the code (not a really good argument, I know).

Comment: @ErikvanBrakel - it's exactly the same reasoning I have. I also like to think that if at some point down the road, where HtmlString is deprecated they will update Html.Raw() to work with the new whatever... and I don't need to change my code. It just feels more generic to use Html.Raw().

Also I would never use HtmlString as a property data type as you don't know where your code will end up in the future.

Answer (score 7):

There is no practical difference.

The `MvcHtmlString.Create` creates an instance of [`MvcHtmlString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring.aspx), while the `Html.Raw` method creates an instance of [`HtmlString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.htmlstring.aspx), but `MvcHtmlString` just inherits from `HtmlString`, so they work the same.

Comment: Just a question : Msdn says for Html.Raw() : Returns markup that is not HTML encoded. / for MvcHtmlString.Create : Creates an HTML-encoded string using the specified text value.  So : encoded / not encoded Html makes not "practical difference", or did I miss something ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus: The result is exactly the same, it's only explained differently. Wrapping a string in a class that implements `IHtmlString` protects the string from being HTML encoded when you output it using the `<%: %>` server tag.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers focus more on the technical differences, if there are any. I think however there is another aspect: They serve different use cases / are used in different situations.

`Html.Raw(...)` is a method of `IHtmlHelper`. These are intented for use in razor views. It can be used to render raw HTML strings 'as is', without them getting encoded.

Since rendering user generated HTML content can be a security risk, it is very important to know when a string can contain HTML code, and for it to be sanitized. One of the main sources of security problems with old languages like ASP and PHP is rendering strings un-encoded per default, so you can see why, per default, ASP.NET MVC renders strings encoded. You want the (few) cases where your program renders a raw HTML string to be 'opt-in' and clear to see.

To better indicate these cases, it is good practice to store the HTML strings in a dedicated data type, like `HtmlString`. These objects will be rendered un-encoded, so you don't need `Html.Raw`. For this you can use `MvcHtmlString.Create(...)`, or, more simply, `new HtmlString(...)`, even if you don't have access to an `IHtmlHelper` (for example in a view model).

To illustrate this, consider this example of a view model for an ASP.NET MVC view with a title that does not contain HTML, and a content that does:

```
class MyViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public HtmlString SomeHtmlContent { get; set; }
}
```

This can be rendered on the page like this - notice that you don't need `Html.Raw` to render the HTML content:

```
<div>
    <h1>@Model.Title</h1>
    
    <div>
        @Model.SomeHtmlContent
    </div>
<div>
```