# Show (ViewData["scripts"] as StringBuilder) in javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I ned help to get this convertet so it comes correctly outi html ;-)

> TestControler.cs

```
String script = viggo.notice(0,"Desværre! Du er ikke logget ind.");

protected void AppendScript(string script)
        {
            ViewData["script"] = new StringBuilder();
            (ViewData["scripts"] as StringBuilder).Append(script);
        }
```

---

> test.cshtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        @Convert.ToString(ViewData["scripts"])
</script>
```

---

> Results

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            viggo.notice(0,&quot;Desv&#230;rre! Du er ikke logget ind.&quot;);

</script>
```

**I want this**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            viggo.notice(0,"Desværre! Du er ikke logget ind.");  
     </script>
```

Comment: `@Html.Raw()` will write string without encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**, this looks better:

```
@Html.Raw(ViewData["scripts"])
```

Try something like this:

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(ViewData["scripts"].ToString())
```

I think the &#230; shouldn't be a problem, this will come out right.

And since `@Html.Raw()` came up: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331019/difference-between-mvchtmlstring-create-and-html-raw) will provide some more information about `@Html.Raw` vs `@MvcHtmlString.Create`.