# How to create a string from c# that can show in View as a rendered anchor tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to create a string in such a way that it should rendered as anchor tag in cshtml page.But instead of anchor tag, it is rendering as string and it shows the string as it is. Can somebody correct me please.

Here is what I am doing

```
string info= "You are on this page. <a href=www.yahoo.com target=_blank >Click to view</a>"
```

Comment: But this information is coming in list. so I am using foreach to show this information.  @foreach (var item in this.Model)
                {
}

Comment: What difference does that make? Use `@Html.Raw(item)` if the value of `item` is the string you have shown above.

Comment: Or MvcHtmlString.Create(item). See this for the difference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331019/difference-between-mvchtmlstring-create-and-html-raw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a list you can loop over the list and then use Html.Raw to display the strings as raw HTML:

```
@foreach(var link in list)
{
    Html.Raw(link);
}
```

Comment: Can we pass this string?

`adasdsad<div>addwde</div><div>https://www.google.com/search?q=sample+link&amp;rlz=1C1CHWA_enIN1032IN1032&amp;sxsrf=APwXEde-ZwfaBWMiBW7hUGv8aGEEgQyi-Q:1682440201890&amp;ei=CQBIZMn6NYqRseMP0LubEA&amp;start=10&amp;sa=N&amp;ved=2ahUKEwiJo9uUusX-AhWKSGwGHdDdBgIQ8NMDegQIBhAW&amp;biw=1745&amp;bih=881&amp;dpr=1.1<br></div>`

Answer (score -2):

```
WebUtility.HtmlEncode("<b>This html format<b>");
```

Comment: Please also add some more description

Comment: OP does NOT want it encoded - this outputs `&lt;div&gt;&lt;b&gt;This html format&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/div&gt;`

Comment: That does the opposite: it encodes, he wants to prevent MVC from encoding it